# Express JS serve public folder via get in sub route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have created an public folder with name asset and i have created two routes adminroute and category route.

```
Admin route file

const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')
const adminRoute=express()

const session =require( 'express-session')
const config =require('../config/config')
adminRoute.use(session({ secret: config.sessionSecret, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true,cookie:{secure:false,maxAge:60000} }));
const bodyParser=require( 'body-parser')
adminRoute.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
adminRoute.set('view engine','ejs');
adminRoute.set('views','./views/admin');
const adminController =require( '../controller/adminController')

//const auth=require('../middleware/adminAuth')
adminRoute.get('/',adminController.loadLogin);

adminRoute.post('/',adminController.verifyLogin);
adminRoute.get('/home',adminController.loadDashboard);
adminRoute.get('/register',adminController.register);
adminRoute.post('/register',adminController.doRegister);

adminRoute.get('/logout',adminController.logout );
const users=require('./userRoute')
adminRoute.use('/users',users)
const category=require('./categoryRoute')
adminRoute.use('/categories', category);
adminRoute.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.redirect('/admin')
})
module.exports =adminRoute

Category route file

const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')
console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/../assets'))
const catRoute=express();
const categoryController=require('../controller/categoryController') ;
const session =require( 'express-session')
const config =require('../config/config')
catRoute.use(session({ secret: config.sessionSecret, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true,cookie:{secure:false,maxAge:60000} }));
const bodyParser=require( 'body-parser')
catRoute.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
catRoute.set('view engine','ejs');
catRoute.set('views','./views/admin');
//const auth=require('../middleware/adminAuth')
catRoute.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../assets')));

catRoute.get('/',categoryController.loadCategories);
catRoute.get('/add',categoryController.loadAddCategory);


module.exports=catRoute
```

both routes using different public folder.

Admin route:- http://localhost:3000/vendor/libs/jquery/jquery.js

Cat route:- http://localhost:3000/admin/vendor/libs/jquery/jquery.js

please suggest why cat route using parent(admin) folder as public folder when accessing js in ejs file.

Comment: What do you mean by "a route uses a folder"?

Comment: You should use a "real" webserver like nginx or apache to serve static files. But what you mean is probably [`express.static()`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thank you guys for your support. i have found by myself, i was using vendor/libs/jquery/jquery.js inside html which causing the issue, i had replaced it with /vendor/libs/jquery/jquery.js and everything seems to be working fine.